# How to logout out of Facebook so that a new FB user can log in using FacebookSDK 5.1.1?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk

While using the Facebook Android SDK 5.1.1 I am attempting to logout a user using `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()`, but after doing this and trying to login into my app with Facebook again I am unable to sign in with a different user because it continues to remember the previous users credentials.

I have tried looking at other answers and it appears most of the solutions say to make sure you call `FacebookSDK.SdkInitialize()`, which does not apply as it is no longer required and is deprecated. I also tried the following which I came across in another answer but it does not fix the problem either:

```
if (AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
        new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), "/me/permissions/",
                null, HttpMethod.DELETE, graphResponse
                -> LoginManager.getInstance().logOut()).executeAsync();
    }
```

I want to make sure every time I try to login with Facebook I am presented to enter credentials.

Comment: Why are people sharing the same device to sign in?

Comment: @WizKid Sometimes people log into an app on their friend's phone. I know I've done that before. Also, for testing purposes it would be nice to be able to easily switch between FB accounts.